# how to move some controllers and views to subfolder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have old project that I want to move it is controllers and views to my new project bu copy and past them, the controller will be pasted in subfolder Http\mod1 and views into Resources\views\mod1, also I will copy the web.php content of the old project and past it into my new project using route grouping for it is routes.

Now since there is a lot of views and controller is there is some way to instruct Laravel that the view that are called by the controllers under group are located under sub folder mod1 ? and how to make the route group point to the controllers inside that group without modifying them one by one?

Comment: you will have to adjust all the references to the views if they are now in a different directory ... you can check the documentation for route groups if you want to see how to adjust the namespace used

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by doing as below.

Move your View file in mod1 subfolder

```
// In your Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers\mod1;
...
return view('mod1/index'); // to return your view inside a method for example.


// In Your route for example you can goup all your controllers in namespace
Route::group([ 'namespace' => 'mod1'] ,function() {
    Route::GET('/user', 'UserController@getuser');
     ...
 });
```